# The following build commands failed: CompileC react-native 0.68

Tags: ios, react-native, command-line-interface, node-modules, updates

I have upgraded my React Native project from version 0.67.2 to 0.68. My iOS app builds locally on Xcode, but when I compile through my cli, I get the following error about React-RCTNetwork:

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/svc-amer-app-jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lmt-gaopnuceteyosgewskokcbczvxjr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sct-RightTrack/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Dev-iphoneos/React-RCTNetwork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RCTNetworking.o /Users/svc-amer-app-jenkins/Home/workspace/LM_Multibranch_Pipeline_dev/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetworking.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-RCTNetwork' from project 'Pods')

I have tried updating pods and updating cli packages, but nothing seems to work. Any guidance would be very helpful, thank you!!